# Facebook SDK - Scroll on the Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

When I go to a specific Facebook tab, I want the facebook page itself to focus on the tab when fully loaded, thus the cover photo of the fanpage is not seen or partially seen on the screen when Facebook tab is fully loaded.

Is this possible?

Please don't say it's FB.Canvas.ScrollTo() , because this is intended for the Facebook App's Content only.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you want to do is not possible.